# Authenticating a virtual machine against a Gerrit git server

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, virtual-machine

I have a CentOS 7 VM hosted on a Scientific Linux machine (Both branches are Red Hat). I'm using docker as the SW to emulate CentOS over SL. Communication between both is done through a bridge (a small VLAN) that is set up by docker itself. It is possible to create more virtual bridges between host and docker VM if necessary. I can connect my SL host to a remote git server sharing my private key through a SSH protocol, and only my private key will grant me access.

My problem is that I cannot find the way to authenticate my hosted CentOS against the git server. I tried to copy the priv key to its .ssh folder but it doesn't work. I need probably to set up more network parameters on my CentOS or find a way to forward SSH traffic to my host machine. Any suggestions?

```
git clone -vvv ssh://<user>@<server>:<port>/project/utils
Cloning into 'utils'...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My .ssh folder was copied from my working git desktop PC to my VM, with same user names and permissions, as said above. The SSH test doesn't work on the host machine client neither, so I think git may redirect SSH authentication to another port. A ssh-keyscan with the URL of the Gerrit repo returns nothing, but this could be the normal procedure of a Gerrit server.

Comment: Not a single reason for the negative...

Comment: That is precisely what is not working.

Comment: Try "ssh -v -v -v ...." and see why ssh fails.

Comment: ssh -v -v -v -T <myname>@<server>:<port>
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
ssh: Could not resolve hostname <server>:<port>: Name or service not known

I've tried changing the permits of my rsa files to use the same user than the host machine, without result.

Comment: I've the same issue with ssh from my host when connecting to the git remote port, yet git works perfectly. I don't think the problem is coming from ssh.

Comment: This is the normal procedure of a Gerrit server. On my local desktop the git client works despite I get the same result from a SSH test.

Comment: Everybody voting negative should at least give a good explanation, specially if they have no idea about what we are talking here and they couldn't help on simpler issues.

Comment: Of course not. Removing the port solved the problem with the ssh authentication. In fact, using -vvv instead of -v -v -v guide me into the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that my RSA key had a password. From my host machine it wasn't necessary to input the password as the ssh-agent was acting as a frontend for my SSH libs and it kept the password encrypted in memory.

This was not the case of the virtual machine, practically empty and only with the .ssh folder (with correct rights and for the correct user). I fixed this and automatized the solution by adding a RUN command in my Dockerfile to change the password to an empty string, which allows to pull from git when building the image. I haven't found any parameter under /etc/ssh that being changed allow me to connect without entering the password, so I must assume that the password step is mandatory in the RSA protocol to ensure confidentiality with the user, even if cyphering with the user's public key is sufficient to ensure it.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea (there's probably a simpler way to achieve the same thing)
 - temporarily configure a read/write mount from your image onto your file system
 - start up a shell inside the container
 - generate a new key pair from within the container and write the key files to disk
 - add the public key to your account on the git server
 - add the private key file to your Docker file and recreate the image so that it will be available next every time the container is restarted.